# Spring MVC, Tiles2, ThymeLeaf and Natural Templating

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, apache-tiles, tiles2

How to effectively use ThymeLeaf natural templating while using Tiles2 as a template engine. I have a simple tiles definition:

```
<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="/**;layout:*" template="templates/{2}_layout">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="templates/header"/>
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/{1}"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="templates/footer"/>
  </definition>
  ...
</tiles-definitions>
```

and my layout

```
<html lang="pl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
  xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{~/css/bootstrap.min.css}" href="../../../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  ... and many others
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-header" tiles:include="header">Header to include</div>
  <div class="container-main" tiles:include="content">Content to include</div>
  <div tiles:include="footer">Footer to include</div>
</body>
```

and a simple content.html template

```
<div id="main" class="panel panel-main">
   <div id="contents" class="panel-body">
       bla bla bla
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that:
If I tried to check the content.html locally then it would not look like it should because I had not defined `<html>` and `<head>` having CSS and JS definitions.

If I added `<html><head>` tags then on runtime I had many html definitions (from header/content/footer templates) on the resulting page!

A perfect solution for me could be that: I would like to define content.html with `<html><head>` tags taking full advantage of natural templating and syntax checking, and then somehow include this file but without these tags (only body or div) Is it possible?

Comment: use thymeleaf with thymeleaf layout dialect. much cleaner approach..

Comment: I found this: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/thymeleaf-template-layouts-in-spring.html. It looks like a very good, simple and elegant solution.

Comment: @MarekRaszewski Won't you have the same problem or do you step away from Tiles2?

Comment: I have left Tiles2 and moved my project into clean ThymeLeaf by using the solution from the link above. Currently I have no problem with it and it looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<!-- /* -->
```

and

```
<!--*/-->.
```

Every tags inside these comments tags are ignore during runtime (They won't show up in the actual page).

```
<!--/*-->
<html> 
    <head> 
      <title>Test</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>
<!--*/-->
        <div>...</div>
<!--/*-->
    <body> 
</html>
<!--*/-->
```